# How to adjust timeseries data in xml files using python

Tags: python, xml, time-series, lxml

Is there a simple way to change data from an xml file using python?
In my case, I have a large xml file containing many timeseries, looking like;

```
<TimeSeries xmlns="http://www.test.nl/test/PI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.etc.org/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.test.nl/test/PI http://something.xsd" version="1.2">
    <timeZone>0.0</timeZone>
    <series>
        <header>
            <locationId>locationA</locationId>
            <parameterId>id</parameterId>
        </header>
        <event date="2017-12-08" time="09:35:00" value="0.039" flag="0"/>
        <event date="2017-12-08" time="09:40:00" value="0.039" flag="0"/>
        <event date="2017-12-08" time="09:45:00" value="0.039" flag="0"/>
        <event date="2017-12-08" time="09:50:00" value="0.039" flag="0"/>
        <event date="2017-12-08" time="09:55:00" value="0.039" flag="0"/>
        <event date="2017-12-08" time="10:00:00" value="0.039" flag="0"/>
        <event date="2017-12-08" time="10:05:00" value="0.038" flag="0"/>
        <event date="2017-12-08" time="10:10:00" value="0.038" flag="0"/>
        <event date="2017-12-08" time="10:15:00" value="0.038" flag="0"/>
....
    </series>
    <series>
        <header>
          etc
```

and this for many locations. I want to replace the assigned number to "value" with numbers given in a .csv file, which can also have different dates & times. Is this possible? The additional information in the xml file should be left the same, but contains a lot more information which changes a lot such that writing a whole new file is not very attractive.

I figured out how to read out the data from the xml file timeseries_import.xml, using something like:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
tree_org = ET.parse('timeseries_import.xml')
root_org = tree_org.getroot()
values = []
for element in root_org.iter():
     if element.tag == '{http://www.test.nl/test/PI}event':
        for i in element.iter():
            values.append(i.attrib['value'])
```

but this gives no structure to replace it, or to find which values belong to which location. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files. Python's `lxml` can run XSLT 1.0 scripts. Specifically, we can transform your CSV to XML data and then run XSLT's [`document()`](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_document.html) function to match XML to XML and return needed new *value*.

Below uses example CSV where `lxml` will produce an XML version whose file, *key.xml*, is hard-coded into XSLT script and @values are updated using your above post as *input.xml*. Be sure both XMLs are in same directory.

**CSV** *(with more data than matches of input)*

```
date,time,value
2017-12-08,09:35:00,0.518
2017-12-08,09:40:00,0.829
2017-12-08,09:45:00,0.311
2017-12-08,09:50:00,0.861
2017-12-08,09:55:00,0.515
2017-12-08,10:00:00,0.560
2017-12-08,10:05:00,0.545
2017-12-08,10:10:00,0.710
2017-12-08,10:15:00,0.847
2017-12-08,10:20:00,0.121
2017-12-08,10:25:00,0.085
2017-12-08,10:30:00,0.163
2017-12-08,10:35:00,0.124
2017-12-09,10:40:00,0.930
2017-12-10,10:45:00,0.804
2017-12-11,10:50:00,0.073
2017-12-12,10:55:00,0.139
2017-12-13,11:00:00,0.010
2017-12-14,11:05:00,0.913
```

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file; uses key.xml generated in Python)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:PI="http://www.test.nl/test/PI" >
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PI:event">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="date_value" select="@date"/>
        <xsl:variable name="time_value" select="@time"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@date|@time"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
           <xsl:value-of select="document('key.xml')/data/row[date = $date_value and
                                                              time = $time_value]/value"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@flag"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python**

```
import csv
import lxml.etree as et

# CREATE XML FROM CSV
root = et.Element('data')

with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    next(r)

    for row in r:        
        dataNode = et.SubElement(root, "row")
        et.SubElement(dataNode, "date").text = row[0]
        et.SubElement(dataNode, "time").text = row[1]
        et.SubElement(dataNode, "value").text = row[2]    

tree_out = et.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding="UTF-8")

with open('key.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tree_out)

# LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
xml = et.parse('input.xml')
xsl = et.parse('xslt_script.xsl')

# TRANSFORM SOURCE XML    
transform = et.XSLT(xsl)        
result = transform(xml)

# OUTPUT TO SCREEN
print(result)

# OUTPUT TO FILE
with open('output.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(result)
```

**Output** *(where @value are changed by corresponding date and time)*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TimeSeries xmlns="http://www.test.nl/test/PI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.etc.org/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.test.nl/test/PI http://something.xsd" version="1.2">
  <timeZone>0.0</timeZone>
  <series>
    <header>
      <locationId>locationA</locationId>
      <parameterId>id</parameterId>
    </header>
    <event date="2017-12-08" time="09:35:00" value="0.518" flag="0"/>
    <event date="2017-12-08" time="09:40:00" value="0.829" flag="0"/>
    <event date="2017-12-08" time="09:45:00" value="0.311" flag="0"/>
    <event date="2017-12-08" time="09:50:00" value="0.861" flag="0"/>
    <event date="2017-12-08" time="09:55:00" value="0.515" flag="0"/>
    <event date="2017-12-08" time="10:00:00" value="0.560" flag="0"/>
    <event date="2017-12-08" time="10:05:00" value="0.545" flag="0"/>
    <event date="2017-12-08" time="10:10:00" value="0.710" flag="0"/>
    <event date="2017-12-08" time="10:15:00" value="0.847" flag="0"/>
  </series>
</TimeSeries>
```